# sscanf and octals

Tags: c, macos, scanf

Why wouldn't it just work?

```
const char* ip =  "192.168.1.4";
unsigned int ip4[4];
sscanf(ip,"%o.%o.%o.%o",ip4,ip4+1,ip4+2,ip4+3); // doesn't work
sscanf(ip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",ip4,ip4+1,ip4+2,ip4+3); // works
```

I checked man pages for scanf(3) and it clearly states that %o is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no "`8`" and "`9`" in octal, so `192` and `168` aren't octal numbers, so `sscanf` can't parse them as octal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Octal number may contain only the digits 0-7. When reading in ip addresses, you are looking for octets, not octals. An octet is a data value with 8 bits.